# How to remove quotation marks from array in python

Tags: python, replace

How to remove quotation marks from array. I am using np.array

my code

```
 c1=np.array([w])
    print(c1)
```

I tried the replace but it didn't work

```
a=str(c1).replace("'",'')
```

my code reads data from a text file and edits it. Subsequently, I will store them in an array and count the combinations from them
my full code

```
import sys
from itertools import combinations 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time
import re


    f = open('nacdata.txt', 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    
    for i in lines:
        if i[0] != '<' and i[0] != '>' and i[0] != '=':
            p = str(' '.join(i.split()))
            #print(p)
            
        else:
            w = i[3:]
            w = ', '.join(w.split())
            #print(w)
            time.sleep(1)
            y = i[2]
            c1=np.array([w])
            print(c1)
```

output

```
['1, 4, 7']
['2, 5, 8']
['3, 6, 9']
['1, 2, 3']
['4, 5, 6']
['7, 8, 9']
['10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18']
['-10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18']
['10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18']
['-10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18']
['19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27']
['-19, -20, -21, -22, -23, -24, -25, -26, -27']
['10, 19, 28']
['11, 20, 29']
['12, 21, 30']
['13, 22, 31']
['14, 23, 32']
['15, 24, 33']
['16, 25, 34']
['17, 26, 35']
['18, 27, 36']
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: print after use replace is the same as the original output. example: ['18, 27, 36']

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
data = "['1, 4, 7']"

data = data.replace("'","")
print(data)
print(type(data))

list_data = data.replace("[","").replace("]","").split(", ")
print(list_data)

list_data = [int(d) for d in list_data]
print(list_data)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 7]
<class 'str'>
['1', '4', '7']
[1, 4, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to convert the data from `c1` into a list of integers? For this, you can do:

```py
c1 = [int(i) for i in c1[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
```